# How to send an xhttp request from an expressjs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

I'm trying to send a post request to linkedin services from my backend.

```
exports.GetAccessToken = function (req, res) {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var decoded = jwt.verify(req.query.jwt_token, MariaDB_config.PUB_key);
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { // handle request response
  if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
    console.log("answer : " + this.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.handleError()
// Send a post request
xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?code=" + decoded.code + "privatestuff", true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

And I get below error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined

This method was working fine until now.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't use `stack` at all.

Comment: @Quentin i don't know what "stack" is. I don't use it from my own.

Comment: Presumably the debugger tells you what file and line it came from.

Comment: why not you are using request-promise npm module ?

Comment: @DeepKakkar — The `request` module which `request-promise` depends on is deprecated. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using "xhttp.handleError()" wrong, I deleted it and now it works fine.